# Parsing a QDomeNode when source xml node text contains escaped special characters

Tags: xml, qt, parsing, qtxml

While using the Qt DOM xml parser I've run into an issue with node elements that contain &lt; in it's text.
The original xml might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
...
    <Material>
        <Name>&lt;Beige&gt;1</Name>
        <Color>#d3bd90</Color>
    </Material>
```

But the parser obviously translates the &lt; and &gt; texts into < and >, probably when QDomDocument::setDocument is called. With the result that calling QDomNode::text() on the name node will give the name as "1" rather then the expected "<Beige>1".

Is there an easy way to get around this problem where the actual text in the name node may contain escaped special characters? Preferably while still allowing me to continue using the Qt DOM parser.

--- Edit ---

Just tested with a SAX reader based on QXmlDefaultHandler with the same result.
QXmlDefaultHandler::characters will only return "1" for the Name element.

Comment: try QDomNode::normalize before QDomNode::toText()

Comment: What you want is toElement(), and then text(), works fine here with your example.